# Passing Java List into included JSP via jsp:param

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to pass a Java list into an included JSP page and am having no luck.

I capture the array in a scriplet on the first JSP page:

```
<% User user = User.getUser(request); %>
```

..and I pass it to the included JSP (which is essentially a header) like this:

```
<jsp:include page="includes/mySubNavigation.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="myColl" value="<%=user.getObjs() %>" />
</jsp:include>
```

The problem comes when I try to iterate over and read the collection to build the subnav:

```
$(function(){
    var myObjs = ${param.myColl}
});
```

The output from this is a String showing the type of Object, i.e.

```
[com.myProj.app.MyCustomObject@87eerftte]
```

Can't I pass an Array into the included JSP via jsp:param? How am I supposed to pass my collection along so it can be read on the included JSP?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 0):

Just using JSP EL to put collection into request scope via:

```
<c:set var="myObjs" value="<%=user.getObjs()%>" scope="request"/>
```

And on the included JSP I access the collection using this:

```
${requestScope.myObjs}
```

Hope this helps somebody.